# click() function is not working in my api what to do?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new learner in advance java. I am trying to save my data through the jQuery and ajax but the data is inserted in the database.
When i click on the submit button without inserting anything in the column there should be an empty entry in the data base but when i filled all my textboxes then it shouldn't be inserted in the db.

[image: htmlcode][image: jscode]

Comment: You are working with javascript and not java based on what you see.
Please post your code here and not in links.

Comment: Please go read [ask], [mcve] and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks, and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as text ([using code formatting](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format »» code/errors/data as an image » nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you getting data in(`console.log(postdata)`),

if yes just add `onclick="addUserdetails()"` to your submit button, for confirmation you just add an alert just below the addUserdetails function.

```
function addUserdetails()
{
alert("Submit is working")
}
```